# Issue with Dynamic Sender Profile in Triggered Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to dynamically change my From Email Address in the Sender Profile for a  Triggered Send.

I tried creating a dynamic sender profile using 'ContentBlockByKey' in the FromName and FromEmail. However, it doesn't work and is picking up the default sender profile when sending the email out. 
Any ideas on how to make this work? Really appreciate the support.

Comment: Just curious, do you really need to use a dynamic Sender Profile? Or would you prefer to define the from name and email address in your API request for the Triggered Send?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are triggering the send, you have two main possibilities:

1. If you're triggering the send from the REST API, you'll be using [this endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm). In this case, as you can see from the documentation, you can set both the `From.Name` and the `From.address`. This overrides that of the Sender profile which you may have selected.
2. On the other hand, if you're using a different method, it get's tricker. The easiest way, in my opinion, is to set up the Sender profile with AMPScript. I'll explain it below.

### Setting up dynamic Sender Profiles with AMPScript

First you want to setup a data extension with the following configuration:

[image: DataExtension]

In that Data Extension, you will populate all the Sender Profiles you need. One row per sender profile.

Once you have that setup, you will create a brand new Sender Profile and in both in the name and the email you will insert the following script:

#### Name

```
%%=lookup("DataExtensionName","FromName", "Id", AttributeValue("senderProfileId"))=%%
```

#### Email

```
%%=lookup("DataExtensionName","FromAddress", "Id", AttributeValue("senderProfileId"))=%%
```

Now, just reference that Sender Profile in your Triggered send and you should be set :)